# Xcode 7: Unable to open instruments from Developer tools

Tags: ios, xcode7, instruments

Iam getting this error when i try to open **istruments** in **Xcode 7** and **Xcode 7.1.**
**"Existing default base temp directory '/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.instruments' has insufficient privileges for user id 505.  Please have the owner delete this directory"**

And screenshot is :

[image]

Comment: So what are the permissions on that directory?

Comment: i am using macbook as administrator account.this warning shouldn't come

Comment: You are misunderstand what being an administrator means.  You don't have elevated privileges all the time, but as an administrator you *can* have elevated privileges.  Now, what are the permissions on that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, there aren't enough permissions of the instruments folder. In rare case, this might happen, if there are multiple admin users logged into the machine in past, and attempted to profile an application using instruments.

For a quick fix:

Go to finder and locate "/Library/Caches" folder, and then select "com.apple.dt.instruments" folder. Right click on it (or double tap, if this is right click is not configured on your mac), and then tap on "Get Info"

Under "Sharing and Permissions:", check if your username has proper access to this folder. It needs to be "Read & Write"

Make sure same permissions are there for all subfolders too.

Hope it helps